# Take a map() created in Python and format the data value to create a .json file

Tags: python, json

The final part of my code to create a readable file is this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        with open("Lista_de_Links.json", "w+", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            trio.run(main)
            links = map(lambda x: mainurl+x, allin)
            f.write(str(list(links)))
```

Where `mainurl` are the `https://example.com` values and `allin` are the values `/value1`, `/value2`, `/value3` (and so on)

Within the file that saves the data, they are saved in this template:

```
['https://example.com/value1','https://example.com/value2','https://example.com/value3']
```

I tried to use `json.dump()` but the error `TypeError: Object of type map is not JSON serializable` delivered, my attempt:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        trio.run(main)
        links = map(lambda x: mainurl+x, allin)
        out_file = open("Lista_de_Links.json", "w+")
  
        json.dump(links, out_file, indent = 6)
        out_file.close()
```

Is there any method that I can format this data model to convert to a `JSON` read model without needing to edit my data creation code?

Comment: How about `json.dump()`?

Comment: Did you bother to do any research on how to read and write JSON with Python? Simply googling "python json" should have found that.

Comment: Hi mate, I tried using this template, but when trying the following error is delivered: TypeError: Object of type map is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the map to a list, just like you do when you use `f.write(str())`.

```
        json.dump(list(links), out_file, indent = 6)
```

Of course, you could have just used a list comprehension instead of `map()` in the first place:

```
links = [mainurl+x for x in allin]
```

Any time you call `map()` with a `lambda`, a list comprehension will be simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much for that question on the ```list()``` I missed to create the right way, sorry for a simple question, I'm still learning!

Comment: actually its bad practice to use map in the way OP is using it. You should suggest making it into a comprehension.